# Xamarin Mac workaround

Tags: macos, xamarin.ios, virtual-machine, xamarin

So I relaize that to develop for IOS you need a mac if you want to use Xamarin Studio (free license). Now I was wondering ***if it is possible to use a VM of mac?***

Also ***do I have to get a development license for IOS if I just want to try using Xamarin with it?***

if so, ***is there a work around?***

Comment: Note: I am going though this because I dont want to pay 300$ to try and use Xamarin, and I don't like Visual Studio (i know there is a trial for it)

Comment: Google should easily answer both of your questions.

Comment: I could not find any answers for these questions on google, that's why i submitied them here.

Comment: I think this question would be more appropriate on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) instead since it's not related to any coding problems.

Comment: I use the latest OS X on my windows box using vmware. Don't tell apple!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The OS X license requires that you use Apple hardware.  There is no workaround that complies with the OS X license.

You do NOT need a paid Apple Developer Account to develop apps.  The iOS SDK is available for free without a paid developer account.  However, you will be limited to testing apps in the iOS simulator.  To deploy apps to iOS hardware for testing you must have a paid Developer Account.  This applies to developing apps with Apple's native tools as well as when using Xamarin's tools for app development.